# I was unable to find additional information about this exception

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine, dotnetrdf

My objective:
build an application for Windows10-64bit that uses Unity and dotNetRDF together to manage a Fuseki triple store.

- Unity 2017.3 64bits
  Scripting Runtime Version: Experimental (.NET 4.6 Equivalent)
  Scripting Backend: Mono
  API Compatible Level: .NET 4.6
- dotNetRFD v2.0.1
  I kept all the dlls associated with net40.

The Unity "game" consists of an single button that has the code provided below. 
When I run the game and press the button, I get the following error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: request started
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.CheckRequestStarted () 
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.set_Accept (System.String value)
```

**Code of  NewBehaviourScript class associated with the button:**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using OntSenseCSharpAPI;
using System;
using VDS.RDF.Query;
using VDS.RDF.Update;

public class NewBehaviourScript : MonoBehaviour {
    private  SparqlRemoteUpdateEndpoint endpoint;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start() {
        // Start access to Sparql End Point : just one time at main method     is enough

        endpoint = new     SparqlRemoteUpdateEndpoint("http://localhost:3030/test/update");

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update() {


    }

    public void oneTriple() {
        String updateCmd =
        "PREFIX ontsense: < http://example.org/sense#> " +
        "PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> " +
        "INSERT DATA" +
        "   {" +
        "       ontsense: dotNetRDF rdf:comment  \"dotNetRDF is a great tool.\"@en . " +
        "}";



        print(updateCmd);
        try
        {                                           // Try to access a resource.
            endpoint.Update(updateCmd);           
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

            print(e);                               // // Call a custom error logging procedure.
            throw;                                  // Re-throw the error. It is likely to interrupt the application
        }
    }
}
```

Note that, If I create a separate Visual Studio project with dotNetRDF package the interaction with Sparql endpoint works perfectly.

For now,  I have adopted the solution to build that application. So, my system works with an application that receives Sparql update commands sent via socket from Unity. Certainly not the ideal form, but until a definitive solution to the problem is obtained it will be used.

Comment: This looks like a low level error with HTTP support in the underlying runtime

Answer (score 0):

From their Docs, it looks like you are supposed to declare a `SparqlParameterizesString update = new SparqlParameterizedString();` and then update it's command text via `update.CommandText("...");`. In the example, they call the ToString() method of the SparqlParameterizesString which tells me they probably insert some logic into the string when you call the ToString() method. In other words, don't pass a pure string to the Update method and you should be fine.

Source of article:
https://github.com/dotnetrdf/dotnetrdf/wiki/UserGuide-Updating-With-SPARQL

Comment: You can happily pass a pure string, the class you mention is for more complex use cases and not a requirement or a factor in this error

Comment: Hi Brandon. It was a good try but,  like RobV preview, do not works. It is worth mentioning that this code structure works perfectly if it is not integrated with the Unity tool. That is, an isolated Visual Studio project

Comment: Unity uses Mono, which is a slimmed down version of the .Net framework. Also, I'm pretty most projects default to .Net 2.0. There should be an option in your project settings to use the experimental .Net 4.6 version of Mono, but keep in mind it is experimental and still may not work. Chances are the library you're working with uses a class that is not a part of Mono.